# Is it possible to make a function behave differently for constant argument or variable argument?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, metaprogramming, compile-time

For example, factorial(n), if the argument is a constant (expression), then the result is deterministic, and can be done at compile time (by using template meta-programming).

Is that possible to just write a single function such that whenever it is called, if the argument is a constant, then the result will be computed at compile time, if it is a variable, then it will do the computation at run time?

Comment: Yes. There's a whole massive part of the C++ standard devoted to that subject, as well as thousands of lines of code of template metaprograms.

Comment: Isn't that the compiler's job? For example, even a "naive" factorial (without template meta-programming) invoked with a constant is evaluated at compile-time by g++ and presumably other modern C++ compilers.

Answer (score 5):

This is precisely what `constexpr` functions exist for. `constexpr` functions were introduced in C++11. When invoked with constant expressions that can be evaluated at compile-time, they tend to be evaluated at compile time (and sometimes you can force this to occur). However, in general it is not possible to provide a guarantee. Otherwise, they are evaluated at run-time (and you can invoke them just as regular functions with constant or non-constant arguments computed at run-time).

Apart from the lack of guarantee of their compile-time evaluation, a `constexpr` function has constraints though: it must consist of only **one single return statement**, so if you're looking for a way to perform computations of any complexity, this won't fit your needs. Nevertheless, `constexpr` functions are probably the closest thing to what you are looking for.

Since you mention the example of the `factorial()` function, here is what this would look like with a `constexpr` function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    return (n == 0) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1);
}

int foo() 
{ 
    int result = 1;
    // do some processing...
    return result; 
}

int main()
{
    int v[factorial(5)]; // Evaluated at compile-time
    cout << factorial(foo()); // Evaluated at run-time
}
```

Comment: What if the function is very complicated (but totally deterministic), such as including loops?

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no requirement from the standard that `constexpr` functions are evaluated at compile time just because their arguments are constant expressions, and compilers do in fact let `constexpr` functions be called with constant arguments at run time.

Comment: @user2016416: in that case the function can't be declared as `constexpr`. It would be just too hard for the compiler to handle it.

Comment: @hvd: OK, technically you're right, although I don't see why a compiler should not execute a constexpr function at compile-time when the input is an expression that is in turn computed or computable at compile-time. But yes, the standard does not mandate it. Anyway for some expressions (e.g. those evaluating to integer types) it's easy to force a compile-time evaluation. Regarding the fact that you can call `constexpr` functions at run-time, I mentioned that too.

Comment: My concern was not theoretical. GCC will treat `constexpr` functions in non-constant-expression context pretty much as regular functions, and inlining may cause them to be evaluated at compile time, but not if the function is too complex. In that case, the compiler really does insert a call to the `constexpr` function with fixed arguments. In constant expression context, the compiler tries extra hard to evaluate the expression at compile time, and this can succeed even where inlining failed. You're right that it's easy to force compile-time evaluation, but it requires a change in the call.

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using C++11? and more importantly, template metaprogramming force the compiler to calculate at compile time, while other methods are just suggestions(?) for the compiler.

Comment: @user2016416: template metaprogramming is indeed *meta*-programming, so yes, it is performed at compile-time, but it is usually done in a functional style that has almost nothing to do with the way you write regular code. Template metaprogramming is a way to instantiate code, and there happen to be techniques for turning this machinery into a computing machine. But that's a very different machine than the one for which you write traditional instructions. In particular, none of the instructions that get *generated* during template instantiation are also *executed* at compile-time.

Comment: @user2016416: so to answer your question, I believe that no, to the best of my knowledge there is no way of achieving compile-time and run-time computation of one same function other than using `constexpr`. With template meta-programming you can write the same function for computing the factorial as I showed in my example, but you would do it in a completely different way.